# Is it possible to write a generic enum-member-name getter?

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function which gets the name of a the enum member passed to it.  Something like:

```
enum Cars {
   dodge,
   ford,
   toyota
}
enum Trucks {
   ford,
   nissan,
   gmc
}
class Foo() {
  truckType : Trucks;
}
const getEnumMemberName = function(enumMember : any) : string {
    //implementation?
}


const main = function() {
   let f = new Foo();
   foo.truckType = Trucks.ford;
   console.log(`Trucktype is ${getEnumMemberName(foo.truckType}`);
}
 
main();
//Should log "Trucktype is ford" to the console
```

I'm thinking this might not  possible if you don't supply the enum type itself to the function because although foo.truckType is typed as Trucks, it looks like all the field is at runtime is a number with no type info available.

I do know that a) I could define the enums as string values rather than default numbers, and I also know that I can get the name of the member if I know the enum name using `let name = Trucks[foo.trucktype]`.  My question is whether you can infer the enum type from a variable typed as an enum such as `truckType : Trucks`, or is that just converted to a number and type info is not available?

Comment: The type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when TS is compiled to JS; and `enum` *values* are just strings or numbers at runtime; there's no "link" back to the enum object.  Numeric enum *object*s, on the other hand, have [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) you can use to get the name from the value. But you can't do this for arbitrary enums without passing in the enum object too, like `getEnumMemberName(Trucks, foo.truckType)`. If that works for you I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected.  I was hoping there was a getType function that I could use somehow to determine the type of a parameter.

Comment: So, do you want an answer (e.g., "no, sorry") along with code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/jwgx4N) as a possible workaround?

Comment: Could be helpful, yes thanks.  Mainly I don't understand what is the type of the Trucks paremeter.

Comment: The code you provided that passes the enum type as Record was quite useful thanks.  If you want to post it I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most features in TypeScript are either:

- from some version of JavaScript (e.g., `class` is ES2015+) and are emitted as-is or [downleveled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#downleveling) depending on whether the target JS version supports the feature; or
- purely type system based (e.g., type annotations, `interface`s) and are just [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) entirely from the emitted JavaScript.

But [`enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are a little weird in that they are neither erased nor emitted as-is.  In the emitted JavaScript, an `enum` object (e.g., `Cars` or `Trucks`) is just a plain old JavaScript object
mapping keys to values.  And these `enum` values (e.g., `Cars.dodge` or `Trucks.gmc`) are just numbers or strings.

Your `Cars` and `Trucks` enums are emitted as something like the following JavaScript:

```
var Cars;
(function (Cars) {
    Cars[Cars["dodge"] = 0] = "dodge";
    Cars[Cars["ford"] = 1] = "ford";
    Cars[Cars["toyota"] = 2] = "toyota";
})(Cars || (Cars = {}));

var Trucks;
(function (Trucks) {
    Trucks[Trucks["ford"] = 0] = "ford";
    Trucks[Trucks["nissan"] = 1] = "nissan";
    Trucks[Trucks["gmc"] = 2] = "gmc";
})(Trucks || (Trucks = {}));
```

That's a bit convoluted, but you can verify that the value of `Cars.dodge` at runtime is just the numbr `0`, as is the value of `Trucks.ford` at runtime.

---

So, if you are asking if it's possible to implement `getEnumMemberName()` such that `getEnumMemberName(Cars.dodge)==="dodge"` and `getEnumMemberName(Trucks.ford)==="ford"`", the answer is unfortunately **no**.  At runtime, `Cars.dodge` and `Trucks.ford` are just `0`, and so `getEnumMemberName(0)` would have to produce both `"dodge"` and `"ford"` depending on information unavailable to it.

---

If you're willing to write `getEnumMemberName()` so that it takes two parameters, with the extra one being the enum *object*, then it's possible to write this, as the missing enum mapping information will now be available.

Since your `Cars` and `Trucks` enums are [numeric](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums), TypeScript already provides a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) for you: e.g., if `Cars.dodge === 0`, then `Cars[0] === "dodge"`.  (This is what the "convoluted" code above is doing.)

If you only need to support numeric enums, then, `getEnumMemberName()` can be implemented via simple object indexing:

```
const getEnumMemberName = function (enumObj: Record<number, string>, enumMember: number): string {
  return enumObj[enumMember];
}
```

Numeric enum objects are considered assignable to `Record<number, string>`: meaning that a `number` key should produce a `string` value, which is due to the reverse mapping.  Then the following code works as expected:

```
  let foo = new Foo();
  foo.truckType = Trucks.ford;
  console.log(`Trucktype is ${getEnumMemberName(Trucks, foo.truckType)}`); 
  // Trucktype is ford
```

---

If you want to write `getEnumMemberName()` and have it work for arbitrary enums (not just `number` but also `string` enums) and you don't have the situation where multiple enum keys have the same value, you could search the enum object instead of relying on the reverse mapping:

```
  const getEnumMemberName = function <T>(enumObj: T, enumMember: T[keyof T]): keyof T {
    const key = (Object.keys(enumObj) as Array<keyof T>).find(k => enumObj[k] === enumMember);
    if (typeof key === "undefined") throw new Error("Not an enum member");
    return key;
  }
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwM5QN4FgBQUoBMD2uA5sADRY4Bm+Cu52UALvgJ76NxYC+WWokUACoIwAYwDWKDA2q16OEAEskSOCHlQiEUd16ZRAGzgqoAMXz40FJiImCWAB2ABCAFxDbkgNy7MWEHAQwEgOcKLAUAAaVgyi+CBIjJrAjACi4BAAssAQAEbACABygREAvFCUYCCijIrxUAAU-BAA8rkAVu4ASsBxtAA8GfkIpFCJCIogRAB8o83ZeQXuQwUAlO7jk0QxODgIKWAIIFDNbe0A2vM5wwC6Pgw8frHxiVAQcJNQ5ZXVtfUNqx2uwMKQqFi+UBAwAA7mYLAD7rswfgAHSMTz2JwQ4RiSQo2S4LxQaw4OIJfAglEGfBEBoAAxxEkYjgiyigABJUCQ0hkFsNikEGozJKNqKj0bjMcBVlw6atEbsAPSKjy45lYtkE6yPazvSYI6zKgDKAAt8GADLgoNTtgAiYXq1koAm2piWRgmiJkpAU4C+PQBIIhMIRACaQO9SW56UgfIKArKFSqNTqx36gmmTQyZ3cgjmvOuSyE53EwDYlCEN3WUFL5aEQNJLyStYhDTOvUYKNrSCzkDOgOMUAAgggEHAWP1a-gKxnVvjJrgGuIvtMTtmOiWbl9SuUrosEPKSVBFBWGo7pzWy9vyraqrhgJRJsBcLbAR6EPhYVDYalRzQGrahTsFAahrgIQT7q+Cp7AcRyXiwCo6s8CRJHqxzfMmfzHACDbWqCYoQt+cL4AaDBUBYaIYiy2KeEg+I0ISR7er6VI0vSDrUWynLRgW+4JkKtGihREp2CyMpytBUDKqqTKcc6DHanoOBoaRODGmaFpWjaUD2p4jrHvJtCuswTCelAzEgtwQA)